# spawn div in random position using hover function, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, button

I'm trying to make a website containing a div that changes its position to a random location using jquery's hover function. So far, the only way I've gotten it to work is to apply the function to a separate, fixed button that moves the div around when you hover over it.

Why can't I just apply the same javascript function to the div class "rand"?

I'm trying to make a website containing a div that changes its position to a random location using jquery's hover function. So far, the only way I've gotten it to work is to apply the function to a separate, fixed button that moves the div around when you hover over it.

Why can't I just apply the same javascript function to the div class "rand"?

```js
$('.new_pos').hover(function() {
  var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth
  var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth));
  var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight));
  var posLog = document.getElementById('pos_log');
  var posXY = 'x: ' + randPosX + '<br />' + 'y: ' + randPosY;

  $('#rand_pos').css('left', randPosX);
  $('#rand_pos').css('top', randPosY);

  posLog.innerHTML = posXY
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rand_pos" class="rand"><img src="Media/MargeDancing_Test01.gif"></div>
<button class="new_pos">Remember</button>
```

I got the source code from this website: https://codepen.io/kaypooma/pen/tAfwm

Answer (score 1):

The div doesn't have a position property, therefore top and left have no effect.

```
#rand_pos {
  position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/calder12/54qfvgnm/1

I'd also suggest using mouseover instead of hover, it's a little less flaky on hover

https://jsfiddle.net/calder12/54qfvgnm/2/

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do! And I see that your code is working on jsfiddle, but when I try to bring it into Dreamweaver I'm having the same problem: the div element remains fixed in the top left corner. I even tried making a new directory that contains only your code and jquery-3.3.1, and it's still not working for me. Is it possible that this is an issue with Dreamweaver?

Comment: And you have that div set as position relative? It might be DreamWeaver's HTML parser, it's a great text editor but it's WYSIWYG is crap.

Comment: Yeah, it's set as relative in a CSS doc. I've had a lot of issues with Dreamweaver and this is only the second website I've built on it, so I may just try switching applications.

Comment: Jk jk, I'm an idiot, the CSS page wasn't linked. Works great - thank you!